# Is Laravel Vapor able to recieve email with the lamda function working as a email server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, laravel-vapor

I have deployed a web app via Laravel Vapor (AWS Lambda scaffolding) which gave me a cloudfront domain to which I point using a simple CNAME in my custom domain registrar DNS settings. The same domain is registered in GSuite to recieve emails. Before I deployed to cloud my VPS had a email server in it so there was no problem. But now the inbox is unreachable. Is the deployed application able to somehow recieve emails? Or rather forwards them to the Gmail inbox? Am I missing the email server?

Comment: Your domain can not be a CNAME record if you also want it to receive email. It needs to be an A record. In route53 you can use an alias A record to point to cloudfront.

Comment: @jordanm is it possible that the ALIAS looks exaclty as the CNAME?